# xDebug installation issue on Mac

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

I'm following https://xdebug.org/docs/install guideline

When I run `sudo make test` In my MAC 2 PHP versions are installed PHP5 & PHP7 as project requires.

```
PHP         : /usr/local/php5/bin/php 
PHP_SAPI    : cli
PHP_VERSION : 7.2.7
```

It gives below error

```
=====================================================================
EXPECTED FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Test for bug #1530: Code coverage incorrect for last code line in a loop [tests/bug01530.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: PHP bug #76046: PHP generates "FE_FREE" opcode on the wrong line.
=====================================================================

You may have found a problem in PHP.
This report can be automatically sent to the PHP QA team at
http://qa.php.net/reports and http://news.php.net/php.qa.reports
This gives us a better understanding of PHP's behavior.
If you don't want to send the report immediately you can choose
option "s" to save it.  You can then email it to qa-reports@lists.php.net later.
Do you want to send this report now? [Yns]:
```

I tried 2-3 times but same issue occurs.

Comment: Use a VM like docker or vagrant.

Comment: Already using VM docker & vagrant

Comment: Why are you using a path `/usr/local/php5/bin/php` if your `PHP_VERSION` is 7.2.7?

Comment: Hi @G4Hu On my apache I have 2 PHP version 5 & 7 setup for different project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason for the test failure is obvious:

> XFAIL REASON: PHP bug [#76046](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76046): PHP generates "FE_FREE" opcode on the wrong line.

you would need to patch `zend_compile.c` in the PHP source code (or wait for a fixed version). without patching `zend_compile.c` test-coverage results might be inaccurate - but nevertheless, common debugging should work. `make test` wouldn't check for it, when `xdebug` wouldn't partially rely on it (the title of the test even explicitly states why it checks for the bug). here's the [diff](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blobdiff;f=Zend/zend_compile.c;h=9c0893b773992fd9fac9585221ef29247352b3c2;hp=f1dd49a223bd96b011333aabbce7fd348087a322;hb=d6595f276fff44aa5d1d2dde7238d540a267d0dd;hpb=9ec519e09499c3f2749e298b097da132f746d4d8), which adds `CG(zend_lineno) = ast->lineno;`. this "fixes the issue 100%" and not only it's symptoms:

```
index f1dd49a..9c0893b 100644 (file)
--- a/Zend/zend_compile.c
+++ b/Zend/zend_compile.c
@@ -4807,6 +4807,7 @@ void zend_compile_foreach(zend_ast *ast) /* {{{ */

        zend_end_loop(opnum_fetch, &reset_node);

+       CG(zend_lineno) = ast->lineno;
        opline = zend_emit_op(NULL, ZEND_FE_FREE, &reset_node, NULL);
}
/* }}} */
```

this bug affects PHP 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 - PHP 5.x was at least not reported.
since this is not a `xdebug` bug, installing even with the failed test shouldn't make anything worse, than it already is. to install `xdebug`, it's not `sudo make test` but `make && sudo make install` (only `make install` requires `sudo`).

Comment: Thanks. How to apply this patch??

Comment: @AnkitShah open `zend_compile.c` go to line `4807` and add the line - or apply the `diff` file - and then build PHP. there's even a slightly improved version of the patch, a little later: http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=b565c85b9e166cbbc024ce279986b18e96048042 - or just wait for having it in the package manager, in case OSX has something alike that. that this make test fails is nothing serious at all - unless you urgently depend on test-coverage data right now; if this should not be the case, just run `make && sudo make install`.

Comment: @AnkitShah if you install `7.2.13` or `7.3.0` it might also be fixed with them. http://php.net/downloads.php ...they were both released on 6th of December - and that bug-fix had been committed on 27th of November. a newer version might be less hassle than to apply the patch - when you have to ask how to do that.

Comment: just checked the change-log; none of these versions has bug #76046 fixed... but chances are good the following releases will have it fixed; it's only a matter of time.